# Problem using Boost in Code::blocks

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, global-variables, codeblocks

I'm trying to configure Code::Blocks (running on Windows, using MinGW) with the Boost library. I have built the library and have installed everything to C:\Program Files\boost_1_47_0.

Within Code::Blocks itself, I have created a global variable, which uses two builtin fields, 'base' and 'include' which both point to the boost installation path.

I have also modified the linker settings under build options and added a link library '$(#boost.lib)'. To test boost, I have put #include  within my project, without actually using the include at all. However, the project doesn't build (it did of course build prior to putting the #include in) and I get a build error originating from "ld.exe" which says "cannot find -l-lstdc++". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: stdc++(that is libstdc++) is the standard C++ library and it has nothing to do with boost. Could you show some code example which triggers the behavior? Do you have the standard libraries installed on your system?

Comment: And I suppose you already looked at this http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef.

Comment: Yeah I've already looked at that. Ok, bizarrely the code now doesn't build, even when the #include <boost/asio> is commented out, which is strange because I'm sure it would build previously, which means I must have done something while trying to get boost to work. I'm not sure what code triggers the behaviour at all, it seems to be something to do with the project setup. Is it possible this is something to do with the linker settings or global variable?

Comment: Linker settings might be indeed as it doesn't appear to find the standard library. Check all your path settings in the IDE and the mingw installation.

Comment: Well, all I've done is add $(#boost.lib) to the linker settings. :S

Comment: Strangely - the project builds without that linker setting.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting says it can't find `-l-lstdc++`; there is an error with the link library settings.

If you try to compile a simple C++ (non-Boost) application on the command line and type:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o -l-lstdc++
```

You'll get the same error as what you see in Code::Blocks:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-lstdc++
```

This is because you're library name is specified as `-lstdc++` when it should just be `stdc++` with out the `-l`. (The `-l` is a flag to tell the compiler that the next word is the name of a library.)

Check your link library settings for an extra `-l`, or try replacing `$(#boost.lib)` with the actual path to the Boost library.